# PayPal buy now button within the facebook application

Tags: facebook, paypal, facebook-apps

I an working on a facebook application using canvas / iframe. 
How I can add PayPal buy now button, as Paypal dont works within iframe?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hyperlink and have the PayPal payment page open up in a new page, or have the button when clicked open up a new window outside of the iFrame.  If you are using the generated HTML button code that was provided by PayPal, just add target="PayPal" to the first line of code.  So it would look like the following.

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```